# Refresh statically generated page (data) once it has loaded on client

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

For example I have some page in Nuxt:

```
data() {
        return {
            items: []
        };
    },
    asyncData() {
        return axios.get('site.com/url')
            .then((response) => {
                return {
                    items: response.data
                };
            });
    },
```

Then I run `npm run generate` and get statically generated html-page with data (items) from backend server. And when I open this page in browser I see that injected data into the page.

But these items might be updated on the backend so I need to see them once I have got refreshed the page with F5 and without running again `npm run generate`.

So looks like I should refetch data in mounted() section. Maybe Nuxt has something more suitable for this?

Answer (score 0):

The only option is use `crawler: false` property in your `nuxt.config.js` file. It will disable static content generation from you dynamic pages. Here is the [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate/#crawler).